# Google Maps: Change infoWindow's Frame

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I've created a marker and added a listener on this marker which opens an info window. My problem is that i can't figure it out how to change the default frame of the infoWindow. is it possible? here is my code:

```
    var markerPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    var shopMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: markerPosition,
                      map: map,
                      icon: iconshop,
                      title: " shop",
                      draggable: false
                });

var content = '<ul class="shopmaplist"> <li>text</li>'
                    +'<li><span>text</span>text</li>'
                    +'</ul><ul class="shoplistel">text</ul></br>'
                    +'<div class="buttonshop"><input type="submit" class="btncontinue" value="text" tabindex="3"></div>';

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                google.maps.event.addListener(shopMarker,'click', (function(shopMarker,content,infowindow){ 
                    return function() {
                       infowindow.setContent(content);
                       infowindow.open(map,shopMarker);
                    };
                })(shopMarker,content,infowindow));
```

In this code what can i do to customize the infoWindow's frame and generally the style?

**Edit:**
the image below is the result that i want when i click the marker.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change a [google.maps.InfoWindow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows).  You can use a "3rd party" InfoWindow replacement like [InfoBubble](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/) or [InfoBox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/) or even create your own [custom overlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/customoverlays)